# ValidationError when creating a SageMaker Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, validationerror, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to AWS and trying to build a model (from the web console) by referring to their [demo](https://youtu.be/1kJf0Lvzj8A?t=36m53s). However, when I try to create the model, it gives me the below error.

> Could not access model data at
>   `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/`*bucket_name*`/models/`*model_name*`-v0.1.hdf5.`
>   Please ensure that the role
>   "arn:aws:iam::*id*:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-*xxx*"
>   exists and that its trust relationship policy allows the action
>   "sts:AssumeRole" for the service principal "sagemaker.amazonaws.com".
>   Also ensure that the role has "s3:GetObject" permissions and that the
>   object is located in **eu-west-1**.

I checked the IAM Role and it has `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` and `AmazonS3FullAccess` policies attached. And also, the trust relationship is also specified for the role (as below).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm specifying the ECR and the S3 path correctly, but I can't figure out what is happening. Can someone help me to fix this?

Sorry if I couldn't provide more info, but I will give any other information if required.

**UPDATE:**

Below are the IAM policies.

**AmazonS3FullAccess**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-xxx**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**AmazonSageMakerFullAccess**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*SageMaker*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*Sagemaker*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*sagemaker*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/SageMaker": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/sagemaker.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_SageMakerEndpoint",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "sagemaker.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add mentioned IAM role's policy document?

Comment: @Asdfg: Updated the post.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake. The model file name and the tar.gz file name should be the same. And my code should read from `/opt/ml/model` folder (I had it as models :( )

Comment: BTW, You can skip S3 permissions if the bucket has "sagemaker" in its name

Comment: Make sure your bucket policy also allows access if you have one attached to your bucket

Answer (score 6):

I think the sagemaker execution policy is missing permission at bucket level. Try adding `"arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"` to the AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-xxx

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

I ran the demo with SageMaker execution policy as below and it works. This is much permissive policy. You can change it as per your bucket name once it works.

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Thanks, this also helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the bucket and the data are persisted in eu-west-1